# jQuery selects all instead of some fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How last search is stored:

```
<div class="lastSearch" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" data-field-no="193" data-value="asd">
    <input type="hidden" data-item-type="1" data-item-no="12">
</div>
```

How fields in form look like:

```
<div class="divBody">
    <label style="top:113.6px;left:32px;width:86.4px;height:12.8px;" data-field-no="190">ID</label>
    <label style="top:67.2px;left:32px;width:86.4px;height:12.8px;" data-field-no="191">Ime</label>
    <label style="top:20.8px;left:32px;width:86.4px;height:12.8px;" data-field-no="192">Tekst</label>
    <input style="top:19.2px;left:123.2px;width:152px;height:16px;" data-field-no="193" id="input-0" type="text" data-param-type="0" value="">  
    <input style="top:65.6px;left:123.2px;width:152px;height:16px;" data-field-no="194" id="input-1" type="text" data-param-type="0" value="">  
    <input style="top:112px;left:123.2px;width:152px;height:16px;" data-field-no="195" id="input-2" type="number" data-param-type="1" value=""> 
</div>
```

This function is used to fill input and select fields in dynamic search form, after that form is loaded.

```
// FILL FIELDS WITH LAST SEARCH VALUES
$("#divTabBody" + tabNo + " .divUpper .lastSearch input[data-field-no][data-value]").each(function () {
    var oldFieldNo = $(this).data('field-no');
    var oldValue = $(this).data('value');

    console.log(oldValue + '   ' + oldFieldNo);

    // not working
    $("#divSearchPopup .divBody input, #divSearchPopup .divBody select").each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('field-no') == oldFieldNo) {
            $(this).val(oldValue);
            return true;
        }
    }); 

    // not working eather
    //$("#divSearchPopup .divBody input").find("[data-field-no='" + oldFieldNo + "']").val(oldValue);
    //$("#divSearchPopup .divBody select").find("[data-field-no='" + oldFieldNo + "']").val(oldValue);

    // also not working
    //$("#divSearchPopup .divBody input[data-field-no='" + oldFieldNo + "']").val(oldValue);
    //$("#divSearchPopup .divBody select[data-field-no='" + oldFieldNo + "']").val(oldValue);
});
```

Variables `oldFieldNo` and `oldValue` are successfully loaded, and the first `each` loop is working fine.

The result I get after this function is that all input and select fields in the form are filled with the last `.lastSearch input` field that exists. Again, the first `each` loop that loops `.lastSearch input` fires only once for each element, so it works fine, but I seem to be unable to find a way to select only one field by `data-field-no` and set only its value to `oldValue`.

Both sections of code marked as **not working** do work (as in: no jQuery or javascript exceptions are thrown), but do not get me the result I want.

Comment: Dashes are ignored when using `data()` and you need to use `.data('fieldNo')` See [**jQuery Data Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Comment: using this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp i found that I can use the dashed ones. It also works just fine through the rest of my project, so why shouldn't it now?

Comment: Fair enough. I always use camelCase as shown in the documentation when using `data()` and dashed attributed but if it works for you, then that's not your issue then.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wanted to keep the tesing as simple as posiible, so I used a form without the `<select>` fields. Aniway, I'll worry about that when I'm able to select all those fields by 'data-field-no` attribute.

Comment: Is `$(this).data('field-no');` an Array? 2 Instances of the same Array are `!==`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by `I seem to be unable to find a way to select only one field by data-field-no and set only its value to oldValue` but when running your code it seems fine, using correct input selector `.divBody input` instead of `.divBody select` I made [**this plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZpvoQSLY1LTaRwJgPmGJ?p=preview) which I think works but can you make your code in your question into a snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Hm.... yes, this seems to be working when isolated like your example. Thatt means something else is the cause of this problem... I'll see into it, maybe edit the question with more code. Thanks, this is valuable information

Comment: @PHPGlue `$(this).data('field-no');` is the number of the field. I don't even understand how you thought it to be an array. Every `data` attribute is a string. I am comparing two `field-no` values from two different arrays. Did you even read the question throughly?

Answer (score 0):

> "How last search is stored:"

**Cause:** when the inner/second `.each` function invoked outer/first `.each` function finished execution (for 3 times). So, `oldFieldNo` & `oldValue` stores the last execution value.

Now, when the second `.each` function executes for 3 times it always get the latest/last value of `oldFieldNo` & `oldValue`.

You can use a wrapper (say, `closure`) passing `oldFieldNo` & `oldValue` for each item. It is immediately invoked function **(function(){})()** so, called immediated for outer `.each` function's iteration.

Try changing the second `.each` function:

```
    $("#divSearchPopup .divBody input, #divSearchPopup .divBody select").each((function(oldFieldNo, oldValue){

    return function () {
      if ($(this).data('field-no') == oldFieldNo) {
        $(this).val(oldValue);
        return true;
    }
  }
})(oldFieldNo, oldValue));
```

Comment: It is so ridiculous, you can use `not` function instead of a lot codes

Comment: Sorry @Sajib, this doesn't seem to work. Im starting to susspect that something is wrong with my namihg scheme